# I am getting an Attribute Error for delete_message, how should I fix this?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot command which deletes the last 200 messages in a certain channel. You have to have a certain role to execute the command successfully.

I am getting an AttributeError that 'Bot' does not have the attribute 'delete_message'. How should I fix this?

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_role("watch announcement purger")
async def clear(ctx):
     channel = client.get_channel(535156631760273428)
     clearLimit = 200
     await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
     async for x in channel.history(limit = clearLimit):
          await client.delete_message(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) and [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("watch announcement purger")
async def clear(ctx):
     channel = client.get_channel(535156631760273428)
     await ctx.message.delete()
     await channel.purge(limit=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this code:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx,limit:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit+1)
    await ctx.send(f"Cleared {limit} messages", delete_after=5)
```

I think this may help with the issue.